# Decrypt secret using ECDH and nodejs crypto

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography

This is the nodejs documentation example:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const alice = crypto.createECDH('secp256k1');
const bob = crypto.createECDH('secp256k1');

// Note: This is a shortcut way to specify one of Alice's previous private
// keys. It would be unwise to use such a predictable private key in a real
// application.
alice.setPrivateKey(
  crypto.createHash('sha256').update('alice', 'utf8').digest()
);

// Bob uses a newly generated cryptographically strong
// pseudorandom key pair bob.generateKeys();

const alice_secret = alice.computeSecret(bob.getPublicKey(), null, 'hex');
const bob_secret = bob.computeSecret(alice.getPublicKey(), null, 'hex');

// alice_secret and bob_secret should be the same shared secret value
console.log(alice_secret === bob_secret);
```

I don't understand where the secret comes in. Suppose I want to decrypt a message `foo-bar` from Bob (encrypted with Alice public key). I have Alice's private and public key, and Bob's encrypted message how can I decrypt the message having all this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The steps above constitute the ECDH key agreement protocol to establish a shared secret (a symmetric key) between Alice and Bob which they can subsequently use to communicate securely.

The secret key  **alice_secret** is computed using Alice's private key and Bob's public key at Alice's end.
The key **bob_secret** is computed using Bob's private key and Alice's public key at Bob's end.

Both keys will be equal. Now Alice and Bob has a shared secret (alice_secret=bob_secret) which they can use to ecnrypt/decrypt messages.

Note that only public keys are exchanged here and a Man-In-The-Middle cannot get hold of either Alice's or Bob's private key.

The shared secret should be ideally converted to a proper symmetric key suitable for algorithms like AES by using a Key Derivation Function. Refer [KDF](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52376/how-to-treat-hash-ecdh-shared-secret-to-use-as-keys-for-aes)

**Pseudo-code**

-Bob encrypts using bob_secret and AES:

```
  var crypto = require('crypto'),
  algo = 'aes-256-ctr',
  var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algo,bob_secret)
  var encrypted = cipher.update("foo-bar",'utf8','hex')
  encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
```

-Alice decrypts:

```
 var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algo,alice_secret)
 var decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted,'hex','utf8')
 decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
```

Comment: Can you provide a small example on how Alice would decrypt Bob message? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Note that this code is **completely insecure** if it is used for more than one message with the same symmetric key (`bob_secret` or `alice_secret`). CTR mode is a streaming mode which exhibits a many-time pad when a IV+key combination is used twice (key and IV are derived deterministically, from the passed `xxx_secret`). It is better to randomly generate a 12 byte IV for each encryption with `crypto.createCipheriv`.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Is it possible to use `crypto.createCipheriv` with `alice_secret` or `bob_secret` as the key attribute?. I have tried but I got an error regarding the key length. Maybe I should use a specific algorithm that supports that key?

Comment: @NicolasDelValle Since `alice_secret` and `bob_secret` are both pseudo-random, you use a simple hash to get a specific length depending on the hash function. SHA-256 should work fine.

Comment: @ArtjomB. So you are saying that instead of using `alice_secret` and `bob_secret` I should generate a hash and use that as a key to cipher and decipher? I really liked the idea that the other party could generate his key just with my public key. If I understood you correctly I would have to give this generated hash to the other party to encrypt his messages and I would decrypt with the same hash.

Comment: @NicolasDelValle No, I mean that each party should run their calculated secret through a hash function to get the actual key.

Comment: @NicolasDelValle there a link discussing key derivation in the answer.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Can you elaborate, please ?
Do you mean that I need to hash secret key, decrypt it before use ?
So both client and server should share the same key for hashing secret ?

Code example of the safe version of this code would be helpful.

Comment: @EduardBondarenko Hashing is a one-way operation. If `alice_secret` is hashed, it can never be "unhashed" or "decrypted". That is why `bob_secret` (which is equal to `alice_secret`) also needs to be hashed in exactly the same way.